# spring integration: "no output-channel or replyChannel header available"

Tags: spring-integration

I'm using the following SI flow:

```
<integration:gateway id="notificationGateway"
             default-request-channel="start" 
             default-reply-channel="end"
             service-interface="com.supplier.NotificationGateway"/>
<integration:channel id="start"/>
<integration:service-activator id="securedFileTransfer" 
                   input-channel="start" 
                   ref="Submitter" 
                   method="submit" 
                   output-channel="end"/>
<integration:publish-subscribe-channel id="end"/>
```

Getting the following error:

```
no output-channel or replyChannel header available?borg.springframework.integration.support.channel.ChannelResolutionException: no output-channel or replyChannel header available
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You shouldn't see that if that's your exact configuration; that usually occurs if someone filters out the replyChannel header - even though you explicitly send the reply to 'end' if the message doesn't have a replyChannel header, the gateway can't correlate the response the request. Run with DEBUG logging and you'll see the message flow through, with its reply channel header.

Comment: Thanks Gary. I was able to to identify the cause with a lot of help from Artem. As I was passing Message objects from one channel to the other, at one occasion I built the message from the payload without copying the headers, thus resetting the value of _MessageHeaders.REPLY_CHANNEL_.

Answer (score 5):

Thanks This post helped me a lot.
Bellow is the code that i used to create the Message header from previous channel message, to newly created message with payload myPayload

```
createSlotGateway.send(MessageBuilder.withPayload(myPayload).copyHeaders(messagePrev.getHeaders()).build());
```